# HttpClient download stuck if connection drops

Tags: c#, .net, download, dotnet-httpclient

I am using HttpClient for downloading files in a C# application (.NET Framework 4.6.1).

The problem with the code below is that if the connection drops during the download the code stuck at the CopyToAsync method.

I have the same problem if I use WebClient.DownloadFileAsync methods but I would like to use HttpClient instead.

```
public class DownloadManager
{
    private readonly HttpClientHandler _handler;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;


    public DownloadManager()
    {
        _handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        _client = new HttpClient(_handler);
    }

    public async Task Download(string url, string file, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await _client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream, 81920, cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                throw new Exception("Download was cancelled");
            }
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set the [timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Yes, I have set `_client.Timeout` without success. According to the documentation the default is 100 seconds. I think this is not related to the stream download but to the web request.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `ReadTimeout` property on the `Stream` that you get from the `HttpClient`. The `ReadTimeout` is by default set to `300_000` (5 minutes).

```cs
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    // stream.CanTimeout -> this returns true
    stream.ReadTimeout = 1000; // ReadTimeout takes number of milliseconds
    await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream, 81920, cancellationToken);
}
```

This works only for .NET Framework. The `stream.CanTimeout` property returns `false` on .NET Core.

Comment: I have set the `ReadTimeout` but the problem persist. Does the `ReadTimeout` affect the `CopyToAsync` method?